# Disable button link on beforeSend ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button link on my view like so:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = Model.Id})" id="My-Btn" class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-role="button">Go Somewhere</a>
```

Now, I am using ajax on my page to submit values to my webApi controller methods, and when I do, I would like the button link to be disabled.  Here is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    method: "DELETE",
    beforeSend: function () {
        disableSendButton();
    },
    success: function() {
        row.remove();

        toastr.options = {
            onHidden: function () {
                window.location.href = redirectUrl;
            },
            timeOut: 2000
        }
        toastr.success("Success.");
    }
});

function disableSendButton() {
    $("#My-Btn").addClass("ui-disabled");
}
```

This does not work for me.  The button is still active during ajax call.  How do I disable this button during ajax call?

Comment: Probably would be better if you included some debugging on your part. Is the function being hit? Is there any other relevant information you can provide?

Comment: Just so you know that you can do `beforeSend: disableSendButton` without creating another `function(){}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
$("#My-Btn").prop('disabled', true).addClass("disabled");
```

And add `CSS`

```
.disabled{
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

This will put a disabled cursor on your button.

Comment: You could use `pointer-events: none` as well, if you wanted to be doubly sure there will be no events raised on that element.

Comment: I swear I have tried `.prop("disabled",true)` and it didn't work.. strange to say the least lol but thank you, your solution works!

Answer (score 1):

can you try this `.attr("disabled", "disabled");` on your button

Comment: Addtionally you could also use $("#My-Btn").removeAttr('href');